# How to interpret a negative correlation of random effects in a mixed-effects model (in R)?

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, interpretation

I've just gotten stuck in interpreting the output for a linear mixed effects model. My model includes Week as a time predictor, and scores on a depression scale as outcome. I have not worked with R before, and while the output is mostly clear to me, there's one part I don't understand. What does my correlation of -0.18 in the random effects mean?

Here's the summary for the lmer model I ran:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: HAMD ~ 1 + week + (1 + week | id)
   Data: MD

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       (Intercept)  8.769   2.961         
          week         2.098   1.448    -0.18
 Residual             10.974   3.313         
Number of obs: 340, groups:  id, 60

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  23.4602     0.5006   46.87
week         -2.3518     0.2165  -10.86
```

Would it then be correct to state that *participants with a higher initial score decrease their depression score less rapidly over time*?

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I think it goes the other way.  A negative correlation means that a larger (more positive) value of the intercept is associated with a smaller (**more negative**) value of the slope, so that a higher initial score would actually lead to a more rapid decrease (more negative slope).

It would probably help to examine/plot the results of `plot(coef(fitted_model)$id)`, which will give you the intercept and slope for every individual.

It would also probably be worth checking the confidence intervals on the correlation (`confint()`) before you worry too much about what it means -- it may not be statistically distinguishable from zero.

Comment: When you put it like that, it suddenly makes a lot more sense. (coef(fitted_model)$id in particular was very useful to me (for anyone reading this question, if you are a visual learner like me try this one - it really helps). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the explanation @BenBolker provided, you might find this graph on "[Covariance between intercepts and slopes](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/videos/random-slopes.html#covar)" by the [Centre for Multilevel Modelling](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/) useful.